# Cannot display different images created using document.createElement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display different images based on a json question id using vanilla javascript and the document.createElement() method. This code will display no images, but if I only try to display one image it will work. Here is the pertainent code:

```
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = 'images/image1'
if (questions.id === 0) {
    questionImageElement.appendChild(img)
}

let img2 = document.createElement('img')
img2.src  = "images/image2"
if(questions.id === 1) {
    questionImageElement.appendChild(img2)
}

let img3 = document.createElement('img')
img3.src  = "images/image3"
if(questions.id === 2) {
    questionImageElement.appendChild(img3)
}

let img4 = document.createElement('img')
img4.src  = "images/image4.png"
if(questions.id === 3) {
    questionImageElement.appendChild(img4)

} else {
    questionImageElement.innerText = " "
}
```

sample json question

```
 {
    id: 0,
    question: ' 1. How many possible values are there for a boolean variable?',
    answers: [
        {text: '1', correct: false},
        {text: '2', correct: true},
        {text: '3', correct: false},
        {text: 'There is an infinite number of possibilities', correct: false}

    ]
},
```

If I only have only one document.createElement() method, the image will display. This way with multiple createElement() methods, it won't work.  I have tried using an array of nodes and entering the array index into the appendChild method e.g. `appendChild(img[0])` but that won't work either. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Is there isa typo here - ` img3.src  = "images/image4.png"`? Should it be img4.src?

Comment: Yes, it edited it.

Comment: Note: You are loading the 4 images every time. If you server doesn't send the proper headers, the browser may request these every time, and start decoding them, which may come with significant network and performance consumption. Instead, if this code is reached only rarely, create a `let src = ""` variable and set it to the value you want depending on your conditions. Then, if `src` has been set, create a single <img> and set its src to the variable. If `src` wasn't set (i.e it's still `""`, then set `questionImageElement.textContent = ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last else statement. The last else statement that you have is clearing all of the images from the DOM if the id is not equal to 3. In this case, your id is 0, so what is probably happening is that the images are being added, but then cleared by that else statement.

Comment: That did it.  I tried everything except that, but that worked.  I have to clear innerHTML before each append so it doesn't create additional images to a question image.  Thank you so much.  I've been working on this off and on for days.

Comment: Better keep the last `else` but add `else` statements between every `if(){}` block, so that if the `id` is neither of the expected values the element's text content is cleared as was initially thought.